# Access symbol table within a program to print field names of a structure

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I would like to print all the field names of a structure (I am working with Visual Studio 2012).

Now, I know that the field name information is lost in the binary, but it is present at compilation. So if somehow, I could get access to the structure's symbol table in the code then I should be able to print the field names.

The use case is that a structure's definition may change with different architectures and instead of writing architecture dependent code, I would like to access the field names from the symbol table directly.

**EDIT:**

The structure whose field name I am interested in is "_CONTEXT" present in "winnt.h". It has multiple definitions and I would like to  print the definition on the current architecture without writing architecture dependent code.

Answer (score 0):

Portably you cannot do this in C/C++ as the language doesn't have **reflection** as in C# or Java. You may write your own function that prints the names, types, sizes into some `string` object. You may have an interface with virtual function `RenderMembers` (or similar). Let all needed classes/structs inherit from it and implement it.

MFC `RUNTIME_CLASS` has something similar.

Comment: Then you simply cannot do it. Reverse engineering won't work well. Field names would be incorrect if you try to reverse-engineer.

Comment: If you are saying that EXE is built using `/DEBUG` flag, and you have the PDB. That's a different story. It would be really hard.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it if the EXE is built with `/DEBUG` flag.

Comment: *"so I cannot recompile any code to have its field names printed.."* and now you are saying otherwise?

Comment: Sorry about that, I misinterpreted. I can recompile my test code. I will remove the edit

Comment: You should re-think and re-phrase the question. :)